# Pointer to two different structures

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

I have three structures `header`, `dataA`, and `dataB`. The `header` will determine the structure that will be used. The `dataA` and `dataB` have almost the same structure (let's say):

```
struct dataA
{
    int   intValue;
    char  reserved1[8];
    float floatValue;
    char  reserved2[4];
    short shortValue;
};

struct dataA
{
    int   intValue;
    short shortValue;
    char  reserved[2];
    float floatValue;
};
```

I want to print it like:

```
sprintf(outStr, "%i, %f, %s", p->intValue, p->floatValue, p->shortValue);
```

-- OR --

```
sprintf(outStr, "%i, %f, %s", p.intValue, p.floatValue, p.shortValue);
```

How do I declare `p`? (**NOTE:** Both `dataA` and `dataB` have a large structure but almost the same data, except for those that are ***reserved*** values.)

I am thinking something like this:

```
void * p;

if (header->type==1)
   p = (dataA*)(pData);
else if (header->type==2)
   p = (dataB*)(pData);

// print all data here
```

**NOTE:** The `pData` here is a pointer to a (raw) data that I will be read. I only need those non-*reserved* values and disregard the *reserved* values.

Comment: Are you able to change the type definitions?

Answer (score 7):

Move the printing logic into a function template:

```
template <typename T>
int print_data(char* const str, std::size_t const len, T const* const p)
{
    return std::snprintf(
        str, len,
        "%i, %f, %s",
        p->intValue, p->floatValue, p->shortValue);
}
```

Then call this function from your switching logic:

```
if (header->type==1)
    print_data(str, len, static_cast<dataA const*>(pData));
else if (header->type==2)
    print_data(str, len, static_cast<dataB const*>(pData));
```

If you plan on using `std::snprintf`, it would be a good idea to add `static_assert`s to the `print_data` function template to ensure that the types of the data members of `T` are the types that you expect, just to be sure.

Note that if your platform has strict alignment requirements and the data pointed to by `pData` is not guaranteed to be correctly aligned for all of your target types, you will need to replace the cast with a copy of bytes into a suitably aligned buffer.